# Magento reindexing of indexes database table name?

Tags: magento, indexing

Which tables are connected with the process of **reindexing** of **index** in magento.
Please share any documents available for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Can't take credit for this as it is taken from original post at: [Can someone explain Magentos Indexing feature in detail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945307/can-someone-explain-magentos-indexing-feature-in-detail)

Magento's indexing is only similar to database-level indexing in spirit. As Anton states, it is a process of denormalization to allow faster operation of a site. Let me try to explain some of the thoughts behind the Magento database structure and why it makes indexing necessary to operate at speed.

In a more "typical" MySQL database, a table for storing catalog products would be structured something like this:

```
PRODUCT:
    product_id INT
    sku        VARCHAR
    name       VARCHAR
    size       VARCHAR
    longdesc   VARCHAR
    shortdesc  VARCHAR
    ... etc ...
```

This is fast for retrieval, but it leaves a fundamental problem for a piece of eCommerce software: what do you do when you want to add more attributes? What if you sell toys, and rather than a size column, you need age_range? Well, you could add another column, but it should be clear that in a large store (think Walmart, for instance), this would result in rows that are 90% empty and attempting to maintenance new attributes is nigh impossible.

To combat this problem, Magento splits tables into smaller units. I don't want to recreate the entire EAV system in this answer, so please accept this simplified model:

```
PRODUCT:
    product_id INT
    sku        VARCHAR

PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTE_VALUES
    product_id   INT
    attribute_id INT
    value        MISC

PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTES
    attribute_id
    name
```

Now it's possible to add attributes at will by entering new values into product_attributes and then putting adjoining records into product_attribute_values. This is basically what Magento does (with a little more respect for datatypes than I've displayed here). In fact, now there's no reason for two products to have identical fields at all, so we can create entire product types with different sets of attributes!

However, this flexibility comes at a cost. If I want to find the color of a shirt in my system (a trivial example), I need to find:

- The product_id of the item (in the product table)
- The attribute_id for color (in the attribute table)
- Finally, the actual value (in the attribute_values table)

Magento used to work like this, but it was dead slow. So, to allow better performance, they made a compromise: once the shop owner has defined the attributes they want, go ahead and generate the big table from the beginning. When something changes, nuke it from space and generate it over again. That way, data is stored primarily in our nice flexible format, but queried from a single table.

These resulting lookup tables are the Magento "indexes". When you re-index, you are blowing up the old table and generating it again.